# Old Database Compatibility in Newer SQL Version

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, compatibility, sql-server-2017

For some of our environment, we have upgraded our SQL Version to 2017. And what we are doing is that we take SQL 2012 database backup and restore it on SQL 2017 through some automated scripts. And same was the case when these databases were migrated to SQL 2012 from SQL 2008 R2. But the compatibility level of our databases is still of 2008 & 2012 because basically we don’t update compatibility level of database during migration. And the sole reason is the difference of memory architecture among these SQL Versions.

So can anyone help me understanding what can be the possible impacts if we upgrade compatibility of our databases to 2017 from 2012 or 2008? And is there any parallel feature that we’ll have to enable/use in order to have minimal impact of compatibility level change on our environment?

Any help in understanding this would be appreciated.

Comment: The differences are described in the documentation and mainly concern features, generated execution plans and statistics, not memory handling. As for differences in memory architecure, what do you mean and *why do you care*? It's the execution plans and statistics you should care about

Answer (score 0):

Adding as an answer as I was running out of space as a comment:

I suspect this question is too broad to be able to provide a comprehensive answer. The best approach might be to simply try the change in a test environment and see what happens. What impact there is will depend largely on your type of workload and what features you're using.

In my experience the biggest catch in these cases when going from a pre-2014 version to a post one is the change to the cardinality estimator. The average query will probably get a little faster but you probably won't notice that because the real problems it solves will have been optimised away. On the other hand there will be a handful of queries that will get slower for you and you'll need to identify these and fix them. As a quick short term fix you can use the hint `OPTION (USE HINT ('FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION'))`

If you're using MERGE statements then there's a risk those might start throwing errors as there's a few known bugs that can appear where the query deadlocks itself, we had to switch to dropping some indexes before merging and re-building them in a big ETL pipeline.